# FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived() not executing

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just started out on Firebase Cloud Messaging, and i set up all dependecies, Firebase service and also its service tags in Manifest.

When sending a message from console, the target users are detected, but the app does not receive a notification. 
So i set up a break point on onMessageReceived(). but it did not get fired up.

Below is my firebase Messaging service

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingServ";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived( RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String notificationBody = "";
    String notificationTitle = "";
    String notificationData = "";

    try{

        notificationData = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
        notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );

    }

    NotificationHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle, 
    notificationBody);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: data: " + notificationData);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: Notification body : " + notificationBody);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: notification title: " + notificationTitle);
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.sys.systec">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">



    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   ...

    <service android:name=".utility.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
             android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: what your message dependency version ?

Comment: it is  'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

Comment: you have to check if your notification has notification message or data message....if it has notification message then fcm will handle the notification so onMessageReceived() will not execute...if you create a notification with only data message then you will have full control on the onMessageReceived() method

Comment: How can i  check if it is notification or data message @unownsp

Comment: if you have a server that sends notification then you can check it how that is creating the notification....if you are using firebase console then it is notification message @JoshM

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using firebase terminal you will face the issue so you can use notification API (use data message)
```

#### API:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

#### Header:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "key=<Server_key>"
```

#### Body:

```
{
    "to": "<Device FCM token>",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Demo tittle",
      "body": "Demo body",
      "mutable_content": true,
      },

   "data": {
    "url": "<media image url>",
    "dl": "<deeplink action>"
      }
}
```

### Refer:

URL: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream.

Comment: Response is success. but does not show the notification or any of the logs from FirebaseMessagingService()

Comment: yes, i have also face this issue so try with the API approach you will get the notification.